# Why this promise does not work?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm playing with Promise.

This is my code :

```
APC.UTIL.AutoDOM = {
   step: -1,  PROMISES : [],          
   add: function (fun) {      
    this.PROMISES.push (fun);

  },          
  run: function () {      
   this.step = 0;   this.nn   = this.PROMISES.length-1; 
   this.PROMISES.push ( function() {this.end();});      

    Promise.all( this.PROMISES).then (   
     function ( ) { APC.UTIL.AutoDOM.step++; console.log("OK"+APC.UTIL.AutoDOM.step);}   
     ).catch(
     function(err) {    console.log(err);}
     ); 
  },
  end: function () {
     this.PROMISES.clear();


  }                  
  }
```

And used so :

```
 APC.UTIL.AutoDOM.add (  function () {console.log("hello1");}   );        
 APC.UTIL.AutoDOM.add (  function () {console.log("hello2");}   );      
 APC.UTIL.AutoDOM.add (  function () {console.log("hello3");}   );      

 APC.UTIL.AutoDOM.run();
```

Only works one time....

> > OK1

Anybody can fix my code ? TH

Comment: Please specify what promise library you're using. And what's the goal. It's easy enough to find why it doesn't work but it's harder to know what you exactly want.

Comment: @dystroy : mmm How can I do to call one function after the other? Any link would be appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean, but maybe you want to call `map` after `all`. What promise library are you using ?

Comment: @dystroy Do I need I library ? I'm playing with pure js.... I'm trying to use the MDN & hml5 rocks indications without success. I'm trying to automate simple functions that manipulate DOM. I want to execute one after the other. I know I can do it implementing callbacks approach but I'd want to try promises. TH.

Comment: I edited my answer. Is that what you want ?

Comment: @dystroy Thanks for your time. I dont understand your code sorry. What I want is to create a way to concatenate 'then''s. As I want I dynamic code (to fill it  with external functions) I'm trying the 'all' aproach but I think I dont understand  it well. Also, I want full secuential execution. And... do I  need a library?

Comment: Do you *need* a library ? Well, it depends on the browsers/engine you're targeting. Also Bluebird is faster and more complete than native libraries today.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61415/discussion-between-civiltomain-and-dystroy).

Comment: `Promise.all()` expects an array of promises, not an array of functions in order to do the job it was primarily designed for.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here in PROMISES isn't an array of promises but an array of functions.
If your goal is to have all those functions executed (possibly in parallel) then to have another function executed with the result of each one, you can do this :

```
Promise
.map(this.PROMISES, function(f){ f() })
.map(function(_, i){ console.log('OK'+(i+1)) })
.finally(function(){ this.PROMISES.clear(); });
```

*Disclaimer : tested with Bluebird*

Comment: A few points questions: (a) In case a promise returning function is added to the `FUNCTIONS` stack, should you not `return f()`? (b) Maybe I'm missing something but what is underscore doing in there? (c) From the code in the question, it would appear that the OP intended that `.clear()` be called synchronously in `.run()`. By calling `.clear()` from a finally clause, is there not a danger that some other process could add more function(s) before the current stack is fully serviced, and for those functions to be discarded without being serviced? That may be the desired behaviour but I doubt it.